# Incrementing as a version number past .9 (php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using an SQL database to store a version number of what I am working on.
I want to be able to select that number, increment it by 0.1 and then insert it back in. The only issue is that when I get to 1.9 and increment by 0.1 it goes to 2.0.

How can I have it increment so it will carry on forever 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13....etc

I am using php to select, increment and insert.

Thanks

EDIT:
The code is nothing to crazy but here it is anyway.

```
$version = $_POST['version']+0.1;
$insert_new_version = "INSERT INTO `DB1`.`Table_Name`.......'".$version."',.....;
```

Comment: Do you have your code in you? can you post it here? so that we can help you.

Comment: Post some code. Also, it sounds like you are storing a single decimal value. That's not going to work. You need to store a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only need to keep an increment so my program knows to differentiate between 1.something and 2.something. So basically to solve my problem I changed my increment to add another decimal place. Now I have 100 revisions to work with which is more than enough.

```
$version = $_POST['version']+0.01;
```